# ASP.NET Mobile Views: Not detecting Firefox Mobile as Mobile

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, user-agent, adaptive-design

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5. I render a bunch of `.mobile` views for some specific scenarios.

I've noticed that the Mozilla Firefox mobile app on Android isn't getting the `.mobile` version of the rendered view, so it's like ASP.NET isn't detecting that the device is mobile.

The user agent string is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:39.0) Gecko/39.0 Firefox/39.0

Is there a way I can globally override the mobile detection to force this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, using the `DisplayModeProvider` in the `System.Web.WebPages` namespace.

You can add your own logic to the `DisplayModeProvider` to determine which view should be rendered.

If you add this to your startup or application initialization:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes
.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
                {
                    ContextCondition = context => {
                        var userAgent = context.GetOverriddenUserAgent();
                        return userAgent.IndexOf("Android", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
                               && userAgent.IndexOf("Mobile", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
                               && userAgent.IndexOf("Firefox", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
                    }
                });
```

This will direct http requests that have `"Android"`, `"Mobile"` and `"Firefox"` in the User Agent string to your views suffixed with *Mobile*.

Similarly, you can create specific overrides and views for specific devices, i.e. a view for iPhone 4, another view for iPhone 5 etc.. More information can be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b696c4/display-mode-provider-in-mvc-5-application/).

Comment: Thanks Anish. I assume this will add to the existing default rules rather than override?

Comment: Yes this will add to the existing rules